# How to get previous and next entries in TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

I have a sorted map, and I'm looking need to find for some key the nearest 'before' and 'after' entries that full-fill some condition.

```
Entry findAfter(TreeMap map, Key key, Predicate p) {
    Entry e = map.higherEntry(key);
    while (e!=null && !p.test(e.getValue())
         e = map.higherEntry(e.getKey());
    return e;
}
```

This seems inefficient because higherEntry in O(logN). Is there a better way?

I wish TreeMap had map.nextEntry(e) that would work in O(1), but as far as I know, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:  `map.tailMap(key)` gives you a `SortedSet` view of `map` containing all keys greater than or equal to `key`.  `map.tailMap(key).entrySet()` would then get you a `Set<Map.Entry>` of all the entries in `map` whose keys are greater than or equal to `key`.  According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet--), an `Iterator` over that `Set` returns the entries in ascending key order.

So maybe something like this would work for you:

```
Entry findAfter(TreeMap map, Key key, Predicate p) {
    for (Entry e : map.tailMap().entrySet()) {
        if (p.test(e.getValue() && 
            !e.getKey().equals(key))
             return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

An iterator over a subset of the keys has got to be a lot closer to *O(1)* than searching all the keys for each successively higher key.